# AWS Lambda function not running concurrently

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function that gets invoked from another function. The first function processes the data and invokes the other when it is finished. The second function will get n instances to run at the same time.

For example the second function takes about 5 seconds (for each invoke) to run; I want this function to run all at the time they are invoked for a total run time of about 5 seconds.

The function takes longer than that and runs each function one at a time until the one prior is finished; this process takes 5*n seconds.

I see that I can scale the function to run up to 1,000 in my region as stated by [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-scaling.html). How can I make this run concurrently? Don't need a code example, just a general process I can look into to fix the problem.

The first function header looks like this: (I have other code that gets the json_file that I left out)

```
def lambda_handler(event=None, context=None):

for n in range(len(json_file)):

    response = client.invoke(
        FunctionName='docker-selenium-lambda-prod-demo',
        InvocationType='RequestResponse',
        Payload=json.dumps(json_file[n])
        )

    responseJson = json.load(response['Payload'])
```

where json_file[n] is being sent to the other function to run.

Comment: How are you calling them function `n` times exactly? Please show the code you are using to invoke the second function from the first function.

Comment: If you are calling the second function n times, but doing it synchronously (i.e. awaiting the result of each invocation), then the first function will wait for each call to the second function to complete before invoking it again. Show your code. We don't even know what language you're working in.

Comment: @MarkB, added in a code snippet

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) for InvocationType.

Comment: can't believed I didn't look into that, tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) about invoke function:

> Invokes a Lambda function. You can invoke a function synchronously (and wait for the response), or asynchronously. **To invoke a function asynchronously,** **set InvocationType to Event** .

If you are using `RequestResponse`, your code **will wait until the lambda called is terminated**.

You can either change `InvocationType` to `Event` or use something like `ThreadPoolExecutor` and wait until all executions are finished